# How to access child json object inside React componnent

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to access values from the following in my react component. 
sample JSON response

```
    additionalinfo: {
          totalCount : 10,   
          missingmetersregisters: {
            missingCounts: {
              mscsMeters: 0,
              mdmsMeters: 0,
              mscsRegisters: 0,
              mdmsRegisters: 0
            }
          },
          intervaldatadifference: {
            intervaldatadifferencecount: 2
          }
        }
```

I am able to access totalCount like this `{additionalinfo.totalCount}` working fine.

But when I try to access `intervaldatadifferencecount` like this throwing exception/error in react component.

> {additionalinfo.intervaldatadifference.intervaldatadifferencecount}

// error case

is there any way to handle this flat single JSON object? I am not an expert in react. 
I also tried to iterate create individual iteration like this.

```
Object.keys(additionalinfo.missingmetersregisters.missingCounts).map((key) => {
  console.log(key) // this returned keys only and I  need values also   
})
```

or is there any better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you are getting when you try to access `{additionalinfo.intervaldatadifference.intervaldatadifferencecount}`?

Answer (score 1):

> Object.keys(additionalinfo.missingmetersregisters.missingCounts).map((key)
>   => {   console.log(key) // this returned keys only and I  need values also    })

To get values use

```
Object.keys(additionalinfo.missingmetersregisters.missingCounts).map((key) => {
  console.log(key) // key
  console.log(additionalinfo.missingmetersregisters.missingCounts[key]) //value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use it like this

```
Object.entries(additionalinfo.missingmetersregisters.missingCounts).map(data=>{console.log('data',data[0],data[1])}); 
//data[0] will be the key and data[1] will be the value
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the objects inside object is straight forward thing. Only that there could be scenarios where one of the objects in the chain could be missing then you need to be cautious while accessing.

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) can be used when there's such scenario and you are not sure whether all the keys in the object will be available or not. Having said that this is a new feature and please make sure to check the compatibility check in the docs before using in your application.

Below is an example for the same

```js
let data = {
  additionalinfo: {
    totalCount: 10,
    missingmetersregisters: {
      missingCounts: {
        mscsMeters: 0,
        mdmsMeters: 0,
        mscsRegisters: 0,
        mdmsRegisters: 0,
      },
    },
    intervaldatadifference: {
      intervaldatadifferencecount: 2,
    },
  },
}

console.log(data.additionalinfo?.totalCount)
console.log(data.additionalinfo?.intervaldatadifference?.intervaldatadifferencecount)
console.log(data?.additionalinfo?.missingmetersregisters?.test)
console.log(data?.additionalinfo?.intervaldatadifferenc?.intervaldatadifferencecount)
```

If this is not compatible with your supported devices or technology versions then there's another way you can access, please refer below for the same.

This is another way of accessing object chain when you know some of the levels in the object chain might be missing.

```js
let data = {
  additionalinfo: {
    totalCount: 10,
    missingmetersregisters: {
      missingCounts: {
        mscsMeters: 0,
        mdmsMeters: 0,
        mscsRegisters: 0,
        mdmsRegisters: 0,
      },
    },
    intervaldatadifference: {
      intervaldatadifferencecount: 2,
    },
  },
}

const {additionalinfo = {}} = data;
const {intervaldatadifference = {}} = additionalinfo;
const {missingmetersregisters = {}} = additionalinfo;
const {intervaldatadifferenc = {}} = additionalinfo;

console.log(additionalinfo.totalCount)
console.log(intervaldatadifference.intervaldatadifferencecount)
console.log(missingmetersregisters.test)
console.log(intervaldatadifferenc.intervaldatadifferencecount)
```

Here I have created a utility to list all the `key-value` pairs of an object by passing the object as a param to the utility.

```js
let data = {
  additionalinfo: {
    totalCount: 10,
    missingmetersregisters: {
      missingCounts: {
        mscsMeters: 0,
        mdmsMeters: 0,
        mscsRegisters: 0,
        mdmsRegisters: 0,
      },
    },
    intervaldatadifference: {
      intervaldatadifferencecount: 2,
    },
  },
}

const listAll = obj => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(`${key} - ${JSON.stringify(value)}`)
  }
}

listAll(data.additionalinfo.missingmetersregisters.missingCounts)
```

Hope this helps.